# Keycloak Java Client Get Fetching Token

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I need to obtain [rpt](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_client_api) in order to register new users in my app.

**Keycloak.json**

```
{
  "realm": "master",
  "auth-server-url" : "http://localhost:8180/auth",
  "resource" : "admin-cli",
  "public-client": true
}
```

**Fetching the rpt:**

```
@GetMapping("rpt")
public String token() {
    var username = environment.getProperty("authServer.admin.username");
    var password = environment.getProperty("authServer.admin.password");
    var req = new AuthorizationRequest();
    var res = this.authzClient.authorization(username, password).authorize(req);
    return res.getToken();
}
```

I get:`java.lang.RuntimeException: Client secret not provided.`

But I am using `admin-cli` that under the master realm which it's access type is `public`.

Already I set:

```
  "public-client": true
```

How can I obtain rpt of `admin-cli`? I will use it to create new users in my applications register page.

Comment: why do you want to obtain RPT for admin-cli? I think you should define a dedicated client for your application.

Comment: @RashaElsayed thanks, I have created a new client that care about user registration and I made it access_type : confidental, I think Keycloak Java Client only supports confidental access_type.